# The applicable cases for the sandwich theorem

Tags: limits

I've only seen the definition for the sandwich theorem in the form $f(x) \leq g(x)\leq h(x)$. But I've  seen multiple questions where one or even both of the inequality signs are just $\lt$.

These cases feel intuitively possible, but why aren't they included in the official statement for the theorem? Are they incorrect?

Comment: If $f(x) < g(x)$ then $f(x) \le g(x)$ as well, so you can still use the sandwich theorem

Comment: Can you post that as answer? That solves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x) < g(x)$ then $f(x) \le g(x)$ as well, so you can still use the sandwich theorem.